# Django: ImportError: No module named sslserver

Tags: python, django

I have setup a django server on centos 7. When I start the server, I encounter this error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x32b6ed8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named sslserver
```

Comment: what is value of `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: `pip install django-sslserver`

Comment: Can you share the output of pip list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the module in your Python distribution or virtualenv:

```
$ pip install django-sslserver
```

Add the application to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...
    "sslserver",
    ...
)
```

Start a SSL-enabled debug server:

```
$ python manage.py runsslserver
```

and access app on https://localhost:8000 or start server on specified port:

```
$ python manage.py runsslserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: @DeathByPenguin Did u read the whole answer? There are many more things here than just *pip install* and GitHub readme. If it did not help you, that doesn't mean it was a bad answer. It was helpful for the OP and he accepted it.

Comment: Weirdly I had to run `pip install django-sslserver` twice. On the first run it said every worked but I got the `No module named sslserver` error. After a second install it worked.