# Django crontab logs :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sslserver'

Tags: python, django, cron, django-cron

I have a django crontab running at the server, if I see it's log it gives me the following error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sslserver'
```

How ever if I runt the cron manually by running `python manage.py crontab run` it runs fine.

Also I tried running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it says dependency already satisfied.

Any idea how can I get past this?

Comment: do `pip freeze` on your server and check if `django-sslserver` is among installed packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ImportError: No module named sslserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500415/django-importerror-no-module-named-sslserver)

Comment: if I do pip freeze, I can see django-sslserver

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi, I have already installed the module

Comment: @Paras did you add sslserver to INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Yes I did, my server is running fine, it is just the cronjobs, and if I run cronjobs manually it works.